# How to write my code in python way of coding?

Tags: python

I have written a raw code in python, How can I make that look more of a python structure,

I haven't created class, objects for each functions and I want to return instead of printing

How can I separate function wise and return at the end?

```
with open(r'features.csv', 'r') as f:
checker = lambda i: bool(i and i.strip())
reader = csv.reader(f)
header = next(reader)
folders = next(
    {
        header[0]: [row[0]],
        'Feature Name': list(filter(checker, row[:1])),
        'Child folder': list(filter(checker, row[1:]))
    } for row in reader
)
foldersinlist = list(folders.values())
lists = sum(foldersinlist, [])
print(lists)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is more a software engineering question. Wrong community I guess.

Comment: Your title is unclear, maybe change it to better suit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if we knew what you were trying to do with the returned data, we could help you a bit more, but this should get you moving in the right direction.

```
def my_function():
    with open(r'features.csv', 'r') as f:
    checker = lambda i: bool(i and i.strip())
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    folders = next(
        {
            header[0]: [row[0]],
            'Feature Name': list(filter(checker, row[:1])),
            'Child folder': list(filter(checker, row[1:]))
        } for row in reader
    )
    foldersinlist = list(folders.values())
    lists = sum(foldersinlist, [])
    # print(lists) #Instead of this, let's return the value:

    return lists

my_data = my_function() #we're setting my_data to the returned-value of my_function

print (my_data) #Now you can us my_data wherever you need the result of my_function
```

Comment: " with open(r'features.csv', 'r') as f: " how to convert file name as an argument?

Comment: So that I can call from terminal

Comment: Instead of `def my_function():` let's use `def my_function(filename):` and instead of `with open(r'features.csv', 'r') as f:` we would do `with open(filename, 'r') as f:`. When it comes time to run the function, we would do `my_function('my_file.csv')`

Comment: I would take the time to learn how basic functions work in python, and how to pass things between them.